# Expected value of square of number of randomly distributed elements

Tags: probability

I have $n$ boxes and $k$ identical balls. Each ball has an equal probability of being placed in any of the boxes. Let $x_i$ be the number of balls in box $i$. What is the expected value

$$E(x_1^2+x_2^2+\ldots+x_n^2)$$

(If you're interested, the inspiration behind this problem is hash tables and the expected access time of each item in the hash table).

Comment: If anyone can think of a more descriptive title, please suggest one! I can't think of a good one at this moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expectation of a sum is the sum of the expectations. So the answer is $nE(X_1^2)$. Note that $X_1$ has binomial distribution, $k$ independent trials, probability of success $\frac{1}{n}$ at each trial.

Recall that the variance of $X_1$ is $k\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)$, so 
$$E(X_1^2)= k\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)+\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)^2.$$

Comment: Thanks! In this case, are we allowed to use the fact that the expectation of a sum is the sum of the expectations because the sum is symmetric in terms of $x_i$? My initial instinct was that the value of $x_1$ would affect the distribution of the values of $x_2, \ldots, x_n$ but I realize this probably shouldn't be the case.

Comment: For **any** random variables $U$ and $V$, whether independent or not, we have $E(U+V)=E(U)+E(V)$. As you observe, in your case the $X_i^2$ are not at all independent, but for the expectation of a sum result this does not matter. The situation is very different, for example, for expectation of a product. The expectation of a sum result is very powerful, it has many uses.